# Relation between logarithmic spirals and the golden ratio

Tags: logarithms, golden-ratio

The polar equation of a logarithmic spiral curve is given by
$$ r= ae^{b\theta} $$
where each point on the curve is described in polar coordinates: $r$ is the distance from the origin and $\theta$ is the angle formed with the x-axis. The parameters $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary.

Here's a description* for a construction scheme of the curve with varying precision (dependent on the number of rays):

> The logarithmic spiral can be constructed from equally spaced rays by
> starting at a point along one ray, and drawing the perpendicular to a
> neighboring ray. As the number of rays approaches infinity, the
> sequence of segments approaches the smooth logarithmic spiral (Hilton
> et al. 1997, pp. 2-3).

Below are some examples* using different number of rays:

[image]

### Questions:

1. Why is it called a *logarithmic* spiral? Is it because the distance between neighbouring points on the x-axis happen to grow logarithmically?
2. Apparently, there is a connection between the logarithmic spiral and the golden ratio. But where does this ratio occur? I reckon it's a limiting length for infinitely many rays, but I fail to see the connection both graphically and algebraically (i.e., can we predict the appearance of a golden ratio using solely the equation?)

---

References:

*:  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicSpiral.html

Comment: It is probably called logarithmic because the radius grows exponentially As for the construction and the golden ratio, I've just sent a message to wolfram.com that the construction is wrong: as the number of rays grows and the angle diminishes the resulting spiral tends closer and closer to a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All spirals of the form $r=e^{b\theta}$ are logarithmic spirals. In complex form this would be expressed as $z=e^{(b+i)\theta}$. The parameter $b$ is called the flair coefficient, defined as $b=\ln g/\Delta\theta$, where $g$ is the growth rate of the radius per $\Delta\theta$. The *golden spiral* is specifically defined by $b=\ln \varphi/(\pi/2)=2\ln \varphi/\pi$, where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio. This means that the radius grows by a factor $\varphi$ for each quarter turn ($90^{\circ}$).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does clear some of confusion. If I may ask in follow-up, why is it called "logarithmic" spiral a priori if the equation is $r=e^{b\theta}$ without further detail given for $b?$

Comment: I suspect that it is called a logarithmic curve because the $\ln r$ is linear in $\theta$.